# Dynamic jms outbound-gateway

Tags: spring, spring-integration

How to create dynamic jms outbound-gateway using spring-integration ? My application has the following architecture,

```
request -> appA -> activemq -> appB -> activemq -> appA -> response
```

I would like to create a service that can send messages to multiple activemq instances. I have gone through the dynamic ftp sample described @ https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp. But i would like to understand how to create dynamic outbound-gateway.

```
<bean id="jmsSecureConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.spring.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="${brokerUrl}" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsPooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsSecureConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="createConnectionOnStartup" value="false" />
    <property name="maxConnections" value="1" />
    <property name="maximumActiveSessionPerConnection" value="1" />
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="10" />
</bean>

<int:channel id="clientGatewayChannel" />

<int:gateway id="jmsMessageServiceGateway"
    service-interface="com.abc.JmsMessageServiceGateway"
    default-request-channel="clientGatewayChannel" />

<int-jms:outbound-gateway request-channel="clientGatewayChannel"
    request-destination-expression="'REQUEST.' + payload.processor"
    reply-destination-expression="'RESPONSE.' + payload.processor"
    extract-request-payload="true" connection-factory="jmsPooledConnectionFactory" />

<bean id="jmsChannelResolver" class="com.abc.JmsChannelResolver" />

<int:channel id="dynamicRouter" />

<int:router input-channel="dynamicRouter"
    expression="@jmsChannelResolver.resolve(payload.processor)" />
```

I can see the request message getting enqueued and dequeued and the response message getting enqueued and dequeued. But then i get an exception,

```
org.springframework.integration.support.channel.ChannelResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available
```

How should i retrieve the response ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means that whatever you are sending to `dynamicRouter` did not originate from a component that set up a `replyChannel` header (examples that do include gateway, inbound gateways and `MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive()` methods).

Or, something has removed that header before the message arrived at `dynamicRouter`.

What you have should work fine as long as the upstream flow is correct.

You need to show the rest of your application.

Comment: Should it be gateway -> router -> outbound-gateway ?

Comment: As I said, somewhere upstream you need something that needs a reply; I itemized examples. If you don't want a reply, you shouldn't be using a gateway (use an outbound channel adapter instead). If you want a reply, but want to send it somewhere else (instead of the caller), one solution is to use a header enricher to set the `replyChannel` header to point to where you want it to go. Another solution is use a reply-channel on the gateway, but that will require you to set up an application context hierarchy (as is discussed in the readme for the dynamic ftp sample (inbound).